# QTableView выборка всех строк

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется QTableView, в котором мне нужно обработать все строки. Проблема заключается в том, что я могу работать только с видимыми строками. Например, я делаю SQL запрос, который собирает 3000 строк.

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
model->setQuery(query);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

Но когда я пытаюсь обратиться к модели и узнать сколько в ней строк, всегда получаю количество видимых строк, но не суммарное количество. То есть код ниже выводит не 3000, а 256. Но если руками прокрутить ползунок в таблице до конца, то в результате я получу свои 3000 строк.

```
QAbstractItemModel *model = ui->tvResearch->model();
qDebug() << model->rowCount();
```

Собственно вопрос заключается вот в чем: как мне обработать все данные из таблицы?

P.S. Я бы мог обрабатывать сам SQL запрос, но этот процесс происходит намного дольше чем работа напрямую со значениями таблицы.

Comment: Так потому он и дольше, что записей больше... или Вы хотите сказать, что он дольше даже в случае, когда запрос возвращает строго 256 (или меньше) записей?

Comment: @Akina да, даже если в запросе и в таблице обрабатываются 3000 записей, записи из таблицы обрабатываются быстрее. Сейчас попробую выложить временные замеры.

Comment: Значит, у tableView более удачная для итерационной обработки структура. Попробуйте подобрать аналогичную невизуальную (массив, коллекция, что-то ещё...).

Comment: @Malice, если работаете с sqlite, то обязательно используйте транзакции. Модель потому у Вас и обрабатывает данные быстрее, нежели чем обычный запрос через `QSqlQuery`, т.к. внутри у себя запускает `start transaction` и `commit`/`rollback`. А загонять все строки из таблицы базы данных в модель - плохое решение с возможно негативными последствиями в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что `QSqlQueryModel` не загружает все строки, как вы выяснили, с целью экономии ресурсов. Ведь результат запроса может содержать миллионы строк, а показать на представлении нужно лишь малю часть.

Для того чтобы вычитать все сроки, нужно использовать инкрементальное чтение которое может реализовать любой (!) наследник `QAbstractItemModel` чем и пользуется `QSqlQueryModel`. Это делается с помощью функций модели [canFetchMore и fetchMore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html) следующим способом:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
    for(; i < model->rowCount(); ++i)
    {
        // обрабатывам очередную порцию строк
    }
}
while(    model->canFetchMore(model->index(-1,-1)) 
      && (model->fetchMore   (model->index(-1,-1)), true) )

// или так
for(int i = 0;    i < model->rowCount()
              || (       model->canFetchModel(model->index(-1, -1))
                  &&    (model->fetchMode    (model->index(-1, -1)), true)
                  && i < model->rowCount()
                 )
    ; ++i
   )
{ 
   // обрабатываем строки
}
```

Дополнительно хочу отметить, что после такого чтения все 3000 строк теперь будут содержаться в модели.

И еще. Идеология Qt предпологает, что модель предназначена прежде всего для обслуживания представлений с которыми они связаны. Поэтому не правильно использовать модель для обработки данных, если это не требуется представлению. То есть если вам нужно просто что-то посчитать или поменять в данных и эти функции не являются функциями представления, то правильно использовать "внемодельные" средства.